# How make a headless cms works on network?

Tags: api, server, content-management-system, hosting, strapi

I made a Strapi app, and is fine and works.

But I don't want the server living in my localhost.
What I have to do?
I want like a traditional api on the internet

I try to search info but I am lost

Answer (score 0):

there are a range of options, some of the most popular are Digital Ocean and Heroku:

https://strapi.io/blog/how-i-hosted-my-strapi-cms-driven-website-for-free
https://strapi.io/try-digitalocean
https://medium.com/@leodeo/deploying-strapi-version-4-on-linode-or-any-cloud-host-using-pm2-via-github-and-accessing-it-from-da87b52b7202

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot! :) I will check those notes